# Saving my own created entites while updating in EDMX

Tags: entity-framework, entity, edmx

I have created my own entities in edmx i.e. temp table for a stored procedure.
Now when i update my EDMX and adds or update any table, the entity which i created (for temp table) is removed from SSDL portion.

Is there any way that my changes are not lost. Mean can extend EDMX or any other way.....

Thanks...

Comment: You mapped a temp table? Really? I wouldn't go there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem of Update model from database wizard. All manual changes in the model are discarded.
It was not fixed in VS 2010 RTM.

Comment: That's not right. Changes in SSDL (only!) are discarded *if* they're a part of the SSDL which the wizard *could* generate. Tables are supported in the wizard, so they'll be regenerated. If you drop a (temp or other) table from a DB, it will be removed from the model. That's not a bug; it's a feature.

Comment: Craig Stuntz: U are correct to say that if table is removed from the DB then it is removed from SSDL portion. For a time consider this example: I have added <OnDelete Action="Cascade"></OnDelete> on my association. Next time if i update the model from DB my this association is delete, and i have to again write this. 
Like this i have created 3 temp entity in my EDMX. Now if i update my model my temp entities are delete. I don't want to happen this. I want to save these changes.
Yes this a bug/featurte in entity framework. But there should be solution(feature), if i dont want to do this.

Comment: The only bug here is that you mapped a temp table, IMHO. Just don't do that.